# Classic ASP XML parse issue

Tags: asp.net, xml, parsing

```
<tour-objects>
  <object model="tourname" tn="1">
    <field name="name" type="CharField">Tour Name 1</field>
    <field name="tour_image" type="FileField">http://url.com/images/picture.jpg</field>
  </object>
  <object model="tourname" tn="2">
    <field name="name" type="CharField">Tour Name 2</field>
  </object>
  <object model="tourname" tn="3">
    <field name="name" type="CharField">Tour Name 3</field>
  </object>
</tour-objects>
```

Problem with parsing XML with ASP. The XML code structure looks like the one above.

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.Async = False
objXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.ResolveExternals = True
objXML.ValidateOnParse = True
objXML.Load(Server.MapPath("data.xml"))

Set Objects = objXML.SelectNodes("//tour-objects/object[@model='tourname']")

For i = 0 To Objects.Length-1

    For Each objNode In Objects(i).childNodes

        Select Case Lcase(objNode.nodeName)
            Case "field"
            fld = objNode.getAttribute("name")
            Select Case fld
                Case "name"
                    txt_name = objNode.text
                Case "tour_image"
                    txt_tour_image = objNode.text
            End Select
        End Select

    Next    
    Response.Write("name: " & txt_name &"<br>")
    Response.Write("tour_image: " & txt_tour_image &"<br><br>")
Next
```

Tour_image is not included in every node. So when I parse, I get the following error. It looks like the tour_image section is on the 2nd and 3rd nodes.

```
name: Tour Name 1
tour_image: http://url.com/images/picture.jpg

name: Tour Name 2
tour_image: http://url.com/images/picture.jpg

name: Tour Name 3
tour_image: http://url.com/images/picture.jpg
```

Where am I making mistakes? I'll be happy if you can help me.

Comment: Please write English in this site. We cannot read Turkish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

txt_name and txt_tour_image are defined once. What is happening is the first object node sets txt_tour_image to http://url.com/images/picture.jpg. The next object doesn't have a field with the name tour_image. Since it doesn't have one, the txt_tour_image doesn't change and will remain the same until it there is a node with a tour_image.

As soon as you enter your for loop, you need to reset those two variables

```
For i = 0 To Objects.Length-1
      txt_name = ""
      txt_tour_image = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited the code and it worked fine. I wish you success in your work.